# Why when requesting the shape of a numpy array within a cython function I get 8 dimensions?

Tags: python, cython

I have the following function,

```
%%cython  
cdef cytest(double[:,:] arr):
  return print(arr.shape)      
def pytest(arr):
  return cytest(arr)
```

I run pytest with the following numpy array,

```
dummy = np.ones((2,2))  
pytest(dummy)
```

I get the following result,

```
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in `C`, arrays have shapes that are fixed. The maximum number of dimension that a `cython` array can have is 8. Cython stores all dimension of an array in this fixed length array.

This can be verified by doing this:

```
%%cython  
cdef cytest(double[:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:] arr): # works up to 8 ':'
    return arr.shape  
def pytest(arr):
    return cytest(arr)
```

When compiling it, it throw this error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef cytest(double[:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:] arr):
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/path/to/_cython_magic_9a9aea2a10d5eb901ad6987411e371dd.pyx:1:19: More dimensions than the maximum number of buffer dimensions were used.
```

This essentially means the preset maximum amount of dimension is 8, I assume you can change this by changing the cython_magic source file.

Comment: Thank you @Rock Li! I did not see any of this in the cython documentation. So If I wanted to initialize a new array within my cython function I just keep the first entries in this case...